# Liveness Probe, Readiness Probe not called in expected duration

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-monitoring, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

On GKE, I tried to use readiness probe/ liveness probe , and post alert using monitoring https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui

as a test, I create a pod which has readiness probe/ liveness probe. Probe check failed everytime, as I expected.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-http
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/liveness
    args:
    - /server
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 8080
        httpHeaders:
        - name: X-Custom-Header
          value: Awesome
      initialDelaySeconds: 0
      periodSeconds: 10      
      timeoutSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      failureThreshold: 3
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 8080
        httpHeaders:
        - name: X-Custom-Header
          value: Awesome
      initialDelaySeconds: 20
      periodSeconds: 60
      timeoutSeconds: 30      
      successThreshold: 1
      failureThreshold: 3
```

And checking GCP log, both error logs showed up based on periodSeconds first.

Readiness probe: every 10 seconds

> 2021-02-21 13:26:30.000 JST
> Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500

> 2021-02-21 13:26:40.000 JST
> Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500

Liveness probe: every 1 minute

> 2021-02-21 13:25:40.000 JST
> Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500

> 2021-02-21 13:26:40.000 JST
> Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500

But, after running this pod several minutes

- Liveness probe check didn't not called anymore
- Readiness probe check called but interval became long ( maximum interval looks about 10 minutes)

```
$ kubectl get event
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON      OBJECT              MESSAGE
30m         Normal    Pulling     pod/liveness-http   Pulling image "k8s.gcr.io/liveness"
25m         Warning   Unhealthy   pod/liveness-http   Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
20m         Warning   BackOff     pod/liveness-http   Back-off restarting failed container
20m         Normal    Scheduled   pod/liveness-http   Successfully assigned default/liveness-http to gke-cluster-default-pool-8bc9c75c-rfgc
17m         Normal    Pulling     pod/liveness-http   Pulling image "k8s.gcr.io/liveness"
17m         Normal    Pulled      pod/liveness-http   Successfully pulled image "k8s.gcr.io/liveness"
17m         Normal    Created     pod/liveness-http   Created container liveness
20m         Normal    Started     pod/liveness-http   Started container liveness
4m59s       Warning   Unhealthy   pod/liveness-http   Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
17m         Warning   Unhealthy   pod/liveness-http   Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
17m         Normal    Killing     pod/liveness-http   Container liveness failed liveness probe, will be restarted
```

---

In my plan, I would create alert policy, whose condition is like

- if liveness probe error happens 3 times in 3 minutes

but if probe check didn't called as I expect, these policy didn't work; even if pod is not running, alert became fixed

---

Why Liveness probe didn't run, and interval of Readiness probe changed ?

Note: if there are other good alert policy to check liveness of pod, I would not care that behavior. I appreciate it if someone would advice me what kind of alert policy is ideal to check pod.

Comment: What GKE version are you used? Could you advise what exactly policy did you create?

Comment: @PjoterS cluster version is  `1.18.12-gke.1210` . **Metric** is `jsonPayload.reason="Unhealthy" AND resource.type="k8s_pod" AND severity="WARNING"` . **alert policy** is  `trigger:1 alignment_period:600s` with the metric

Answer (score 2):

### Background

In [Configure Liveness, Readiness and Startup Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes) documentation you can find information:

> The kubelet uses `liveness probes` to know when to restart a container. For example, liveness probes could catch a deadlock, where an application is running, but unable to make progress. Restarting a container in such a state can help to make the application more available despite bugs.
>
> The kubelet uses `readiness probes` to know when a container is ready to start accepting traffic. A Pod is considered ready when all of its containers are ready. One use of this signal is to control which Pods are used as backends for Services. When a Pod is not ready, it is removed from Service load balancers.

As `GKE` master is managed by google, you won't find `kubelet` logs using `CLI` (you might try to use `Stackdriver`). I've tested it on the `Kubeadm` cluster and set the `verbosity` level to `8`.

When you are using `$ kubectl get events` you are getting events only from the last hour (it can be changed in Kubernetes settings - `Kubeadm` but I don't think it can be changed in `GKE` as master is managed by google.)

```
$ kubectl get events
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON                    OBJECT              MESSAGE
37m         Normal    Starting                  node/kubeadm        Starting kubelet.
...
33m         Normal    Scheduled                 pod/liveness-http   Successfully assigned default/liveness-http to kubeadm
33m         Normal    Pulling                   pod/liveness-http   Pulling image "k8s.gcr.io/liveness"
33m         Normal    Pulled                    pod/liveness-http   Successfully pulled image "k8s.gcr.io/liveness" in 893.953679ms
33m         Normal    Created                   pod/liveness-http   Created container liveness
33m         Normal    Started                   pod/liveness-http   Started container liveness
3m12s       Warning   Unhealthy                 pod/liveness-http   Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
30m         Warning   Unhealthy                 pod/liveness-http   Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
8m17s       Warning   BackOff                   pod/liveness-http   Back-off restarting failed container
```

Again the same command after `~1 hour`.

```
$ kubectl get events
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON      OBJECT              MESSAGE
33s         Normal    Pulling     pod/liveness-http   Pulling image "k8s.gcr.io/liveness"
5m40s       Warning   Unhealthy   pod/liveness-http   Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
15m         Warning   BackOff     pod/liveness-http   Back-off restarting failed container
```

### Tests

The `Readiness Probe` check is executed each 10 seconds for more than one hour.

```
Mar 09 14:48:34 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 14:48:34.222085    3855 prober.go:117] Readiness probe for "liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4562a):liveness" failed (failure): HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
Mar 09 14:48:44 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 14:48:44.221782    3855 prober.go:117] Readiness probe for "liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4562a):liveness" failed (failure): HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
Mar 09 14:48:54 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 14:48:54.221828    3855 prober.go:117] Readiness probe for "liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4562a):liveness" failed (failure): HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
...
Mar 09 15:01:34 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 15:01:34.222491    3855 prober.go:117] Readiness probe for "liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4
562a):liveness" failed (failure): HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
Mar 09 15:01:44 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 15:01:44.221877    3855 prober.go:117] Readiness probe for "liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4562a):liveness" failed (failure): HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
Mar 09 15:01:54 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 15:01:54.221976    3855 prober.go:117] Readiness probe for "liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4562a):liveness" failed (failure): HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
...
Mar 09 15:10:14 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 15:10:14.222163    3855 prober.go:117] Readiness probe for "liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4562a):liveness" failed (failure): HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
Mar 09 15:10:24 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 15:10:24.221744    3855 prober.go:117] Readiness probe for "liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4562a):liveness" failed (failure): HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
Mar 09 15:10:34 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 15:10:34.223877    3855 prober.go:117] Readiness probe for "liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4562a):liveness" failed (failure): HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
...
Mar 09 16:04:14 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 16:04:14.222853    3855 prober.go:117] Readiness probe for "liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4562a):liveness" failed (failure): HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
Mar 09 16:04:24 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 16:04:24.222531    3855 prober.go:117] Readiness probe for "liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4562a):liveness" failed (failure): HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
```

Also, there are `Liveness probe` entries.

```
Mar 09 16:12:58 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 16:12:58.462878    3855 prober.go:117] Liveness probe for "liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4562a):liveness" failed (failure): HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
Mar 09 16:13:58 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 16:13:58.462906    3855 prober.go:117] Liveness probe for "liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4562a):liveness" failed (failure): HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
Mar 09 16:14:58 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 16:14:58.465470    3855 kuberuntime_manager.go:656] Container "liveness" ({"docker" "95567f85708ffac8b34b6c6f2bdb4
9d8eb57e7704b7b416083c7f296dd40cd0b"}) of pod liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4562a): Container liveness failed liveness probe, will be restarted
Mar 09 16:14:58 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 16:14:58.465587    3855 kuberuntime_manager.go:712] Killing unwanted container "liveness"(id={"docker" "95567f85708ffac8b34b6c6f2bdb49d8eb57e7704b7b416083c7f296dd40cd0b"}) for pod "liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4562a)"
```

Total time of tests:

```
$ kubectl get po -w
NAME            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
liveness-http   0/1     Running   21         99m
liveness-http   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   21         101m
liveness-http   0/1     Running            22         106m
liveness-http   1/1     Running            22         106m
liveness-http   0/1     Running            22         106m
liveness-http   0/1     Running            23         109m
liveness-http   1/1     Running            23         109m
liveness-http   0/1     Running            23         109m
liveness-http   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   23         112m
liveness-http   0/1     Running            24         117m
liveness-http   1/1     Running            24         117m
liveness-http   0/1     Running            24         117m
```

### Conclusion

> Liveness probe check didn't not called anymore

`Liveness check` is created when Kubernetes create pod  and is recreated each time that `Pod` is restarted. In your configuration you have set `initialDelaySeconds: 20` so after creating a `pod`, Kubernetes will wait 20 seconds, then it will call `liveness` probe 3 times (as you have set `failureThreshold: 3`). After 3 fails, Kubernetes will restart this pod according to `RestartPolicy`. Also in logs you will be able to find in logs:

```
Mar 09 16:14:58 kubeadm kubelet[3855]: I0309 16:14:58.465470    3855 kuberuntime_manager.go:656] Container "liveness" ({"docker" "95567f85708ffac8b34b6c6f2bdb4
9d8eb57e7704b7b416083c7f296dd40cd0b"}) of pod liveness-http_default(8c87a08e-34aa-4bb1-be9b-fdca39a4562a): Container liveness failed liveness probe, will be restarted
```

Why will it be restarted? Answer can be found in [Container probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes).

> `livenessProbe:` Indicates whether the container is running. If the liveness probe fails, the kubelet kills the container, and the container is subjected to its restart policy.

Default [Restart Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy) in `GKE` is `Always`. So your pod will be restarted over and over again.

> Readiness probe check called but interval became long ( maximum interval looks about 10 minutes)

I think you've come to that conclusion as you have based on `$ kubectl get events` and `$ kubectl describe po`. In both cases, events as default are removed after 1 hour. In my `Tests` part you can see that `Readiness probe` entries are from `14:48:34` till `16:04:24`, so each 10 seconds Kubernetes calls `Readiness Probe`.

> Why Liveness probe didn't run, and interval of Readiness probe changed?

As I show you in the `Tests` part, the `Readiness probe` didn't change. Misleading in this case was using `$ kubectl events`. Regarding `Liveiness Probe` it's still calling but only 3 times after pod will be `created`/`restarted`. Also I've included output of `$ kubectl get po -w`. When `pod` is recreated, you might find in kubelet logs those `liveness probes`.

> In my plan, I would create alert policy, whose condition is like:
>
> - if liveness probe error happens 3 times in 3 minutes

If `liveness probe` fails 3 times, with your current setup it will restart this pod. In that situation you could use each `restart` to create an `alert`.

```
Metric: kubernetes.io/container/restart_count
Resource type: k8s_container
```

Some useful information you can find in Stackoverflow cases regarding `Monitoring alert` like:

- [Monitoring and alerting on pod status or restart with Google Container Engine (GKE) and Stackdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789276/monitoring-and-alerting-on-pod-status-or-restart-with-google-container-engine-g)
- [Can I use Google Cloud Monitoring to monitor a failing Container / Pod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248752/can-i-use-google-cloud-monitoring-to-monitor-a-failing-container-pod)